# Can I turn a headset with a cord into a bluetooth headset with multiple connections?

Tags: bluetooth, audio

I'd like to connect Arduino with bluetooth shield to multiple bluetooth devices (TV & baby monitor), plug a corded headset into the contraption, sprinkle LEDs on top, and do the following:

If there is a signal above certain threshold coming from the baby monitor listen to a mix of TV and baby monitor audio with LEDs blinking; otherwise listen only to TV audio.

Thus the questions:

Can bluetooth connect with multiple devices simultaneously?

What do I need to implement that?

Comment: AFAIK bluetooth does not support multiple connections, but I'm not really into BT4. As for BT2.0, you will need two bluetooth audio-enabled masters; connect them to the two sources and then you will have your audio signals and you can mix them or not. Arduino is not really needed if you can configure the modules from e.g. a pc. Anyway I don't know any BT2.0 audio master board. BT4 has profiles, but I don't know if you can take a general purpose BT4 board and get an audio stream from it...